# How do I change the close/maximise/minimise button sizes in 13.10?

Tags: unity, window

How could I change the button size for the window controls. I'm using a touch screen and I'm having difficulty hitting the right one. I've tried adjusting fonts but this does not help.

Any ideas folks?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `gnome-color-chooser`

Answer (score -1):

For this one - I actually use `gnome-tweak-tool` for that one.

```
sudo apt-get install -y gnome-tweak-tool
```

This will enable you to customize almost everything to your preference.  There are another two apps that would give you more options.

```
unity-tweak-tool
ubuntu-tweak
```